# netcat: listen and capture TCP packets

Tags: pcap, tcpdump, netcat

Is it possible to just listen(not create a new connection) for TCP packets on a port which is already in use, i.e. is sending over data from a router to a server.

I am aware that the following starts the listening process on the mentioned port, and saves it in the `pcap` file:

SERVER SIDE: `nc  -l -p <port> > file_name.pcap`

CLIENT SIDE: `sudo tcpdump -s 0 -U -n -i eth0 not host <server_ip> -w file_name.pcap | nc <server_ip> <port>`

But this creates a new connection on the given port and captures packet related to it. I want to capture packets on a port which is already being used to send packets.

Comment: Why not use tcpdump to trace the connection on that port and then extract the pcap from the traced connection?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I could do that, but I am trying to learn to use nc and was looking to see as to how could I run a tcpdump using the same.

Comment: nc doesn't seem to have any way to do that as it opens and listens at the TCP/UDP layer. Conversely, tcpdump relies on hooks lower in the stack (through AF_PACKET) to dump packets.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying! I had been trying to just figure this out!

Comment: Glad I could help. I posted an answer with more explanations/details. If you're familiar with Python, you might want to check out the link at the end.

Comment: Is there anything you'd like me to detail before accepting the answer?

Comment: Nope, thank you, I am good. The packet sniffer code works well!

Answer (score 5):

**Netcat doesn't seem to have that capability** currently (according to the man page).

---

When listening netcat typically opens a [socket](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socket.2.html) of family `AF_INET` (network layer, i.e., TCP/UDP) and type `SOCK_STREAM` (two-way connection). In contrast, to dump packets, tcpdump opens a socket of family `AF_PACKET` (device driver layer) and type `SOCK_RAW` (direct access to packets received).

You can observe this with strace to trace syscalls (here, `socket` and the subsequent `bind`) and their arguments:

```
$ sudo strace -e trace=socket,bind nc -l 8888 
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP) = 3
bind(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(8888), sin_addr=inet_addr("0.0.0.0")}, 16) = 0
$
$ sudo strace -e trace=socket,bind tcpdump -w tmp.pcap
[...]
socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, 768)        = 3
bind(3, {sa_family=AF_PACKET, proto=0x03, if2, pkttype=PACKET_HOST, addr(0)={0, }, 20) = 0
[...]
```

---

You can dump traffic at the device driver level (like tcpdump) or the network layer by using a socket of type `SOCK_RAW`. I.e., you could very well retrieve the file sent over netcat by opening a socket of family `AF_INET` and type `SOCK_RAW`, as is implemented in [this blog post](https://www.binarytides.com/python-packet-sniffer-code-linux/).